# BeautifulSoup: site not allowing me to view content after login

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Fetlife, and for that of course I need to log in:

```python
base_url = "https://fetlife.com/"
login_route = 'users/sign_in/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36', 'origin': base_url, 'referer': base_url + login_route}
s = requests.session()
s.headers = headers
site = s.get(base_url + login_route)

bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
token = bs_content.find("meta", {"name":"csrf-token"})["content"]

login_payload = {
    'user[login]': '<my username>',
    'user[password]': '<my password>',
    'authenticity_token': token,
    'user[locale]':'en',
    'user[otp_attempt]':'step_1'
}

s.post(base_url + login_route,login_payload)

# access a user's profile to test if i'm logged in
home_page = s.get("<some fetlife user profile url")
print(home_page.content)
```

I'm not getting errors and I'm not getting redirected to the login page when I try to access the user's profile, so I guess the login works? However, I get redirected to a different page, which includes the following:

```
<h3>You shouldn\'t see this!</h3>
<p>If you can see this text that means that you, your computer, or your\nnetwork is blocking access to the FetLife subdomains.</p>
<p>We have seen an increase in this recently.  Here are some resources you can use to help resolve the problem:
<ul>
<li><a href="https://status.fetlife.com/2020/01/29/site-issues-w-dnsbl-tools/">Offsite Information</a></li>
<li><a href="https://fetlife.com/groups/311/posts/15873695">
</ul>
```

Any idea what this means and how to get around it?

Comment: if this persists., then try with proxy IP setting or selenium (once you log in, save the cookie)